# Firestore - How to properly store the document ID in the model class?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is no real documentation about how to properly store the auto-generated ID of a Firestore document in a custom Java object. Retrieving the ID is easy, but how to properly store it to avoid redundancy.

This is my approach:

Model class:

```
public class Note {
    private String documentId;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Note() {
        //public no arg constructor necessary
    }

    public Note(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Load data:

```
public void loadNotes(View v) {
    notebookRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                        note.setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        noteList.add(note);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

My questions:

1) Is the `@Exclude` on the getter method enough? Should I also add it to the setter? Or to the field declaration?

2) Am I missing a more convenient way to handle the document ID in a model class?

Answer (score 16):

There's finally a proper way to do this now. You just need to annotate the field with `@DocumentId`. [More details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html)

In your case

```
public class Note {
   @DocumentId
   private String documentId;
   ...
}
```

As noted by @fuadj, this is available starting on Cloud Firestore version 20.2.0

Comment: I'm getting "cannot find symbol class DocumentId", do i have to include any gradle dependencies to enable this to work?

Comment: The docs explain that it is a feature included in firestore v20.2.0, so requires updating gradle dependencies accordingly https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v20-2-0

Answer (score 3):

[@Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) on the getter is sufficient.

There is not really a "proper" way to do what you're doing.  It looks like you're handling this the way you need, and that's fine.

If you would like to see a more formalized and automated way of mapping the document ID into a javabean, that sounds like a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) you could file.  Maybe another annotation could be added that indicates which field you would like to use to store the ID.

Comment: Thank you! Does adding the @Exlucde annotation to the setter or field have any effect?

Comment: I don't believe so, but you should check that out for yourself.

Comment: Well I did check it, I just want to make sure I didn't miss anything