# How to get the ID of a Firestore document into a RecyclerView - Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create an application able to receive the id of a document on Firestore with all its fields and put them in a RecyclerView Adapter. For now, I can only get the fields, but I don't understand how to get the document ID. This is the code:

Class TestPage:

```
public class TestPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
        progressDialog.show();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userArrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(TestPage.this,userArrayList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        EventChangeListener();

    }

    private void EventChangeListener() {

        db.collection("Attesa").orderBy("firstName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                        if(error != null){
                            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            return;
                        }

                        for(DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){
                            if(dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                                userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class));
                            }
                            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Class User:

```
 public class User {

    String firstName, lastName, age;

    public User(){}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Class MyAdapter:

```
  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder((v));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user = userArrayList.get(position);

        holder.firstName.setText(user.firstName);
        holder.lastName.setText(user.lastName);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView firstName, lastName;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            firstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            lastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the Firestore screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB8oJ.png)

How can I take the ID of the document in addition to firstName and lastName? so in this case the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DocumentId` annotation on the POJO instead, and then let Firestore automatically read it from the database. As the documentation of the [`DocumentId` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId) says:

> Annotation used to mark a POJO property to be automatically populated with the document's ID when the POJO is created from a Cloud Firestore document (for example, via `toObject(Class)`).

So something like:

```
public class User {

    String firstName, lastName, age, docId;

    public User(){}

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String docId) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.docId = docId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @DocumentId
    public String getDocId() {
        return docId;
    }

    @DocumentId
    public void setDocId(String docId) {
        this.docId = docId;
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firestore - How to properly store the document ID in the model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865690/firestore-how-to-properly-store-the-document-id-in-the-model-class)

Comment: Yep, much better solution, as it also reduces the size of the document.